# TestNG & Selenium: Separate tests into "groups", run ordered inside each group

Tags: selenium, integration-testing, webdriver, testng

We use TestNG and Selenium WebDriver to test our web application.

Now our problem is that we often have several tests that need to run in a certain order, e.g.:

- login to application
- enter some data
- edit the data
- check that it's displayed correctly

Now obviously these tests need to run in that precise order.

At the same time, we have many other tests which are totally independent from the list of tests above.

So we'd like to be able to somehow put tests into "groups" (not necessarily groups in the TestNG sense), and then run them such that:

- tests inside one "group" always run together and in the same order
- but different test "groups" as a whole can run in any order

The second point is important, because we want to avoid dependencies between tests in different groups (so different test "groups" can be used and developed independently).

Is there a way to achieve this using TestNG?

**Solutions we tried**

- At first we just put tests that belong together into one class, and used `dependsOnMethods` to make them run in the right order. This used to work in TestNG V5, but in V6 TestNG will sometimes interleave tests from different classes (while respecting the ordering imposed by `dependsOnMethods`). There does not seem to be a way to tell TestNG "Always run tests from one class together".
- We considered writing a [method interceptor](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors). However, this has the disadvantage that running tests from inside an IDE becomes more difficult (because directly invoking a test on a class would not use the interceptor). Also, tests using `dependsOnMethods` cannot be ordered by the interceptor, so we'd have to stop using that. We'd probably have to create our own annotation to specify ordering, and we'd like to use standard TestNG features as far as possible.
- The [TestNG docs](http://testng.org/doc/selenium.html) propose using `preserve-order` to order tests. That looks promising, but only works if you list every test method separately, which seems redundant and hard to maintain.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

I am also open for any other suggestions on how to handle tests that build on each other, without having to impose a total order on *all* tests.

**PS**

alanning's answer points out that we could simply keep all tests independent by doing the necessary setup inside each test. That is in principle a good idea (and some tests do this), however sometimes we need to test a complete workflow, with each step depending on all previous steps (as in my example). To do that with "independent" tests would mean running the same multi-step setup over and over, and that would make our already slow tests even slower. Instead of three tests doing:

- Test 1: login to application
- Test 2: enter some data
- Test 3: edit the data

we would get

- Test 1: login to application
- Test 2: login to application, enter some data
- Test 3: login to application, enter some data, edit the data
  etc.

In addition to needlessly increasing testing time, this also feels unnatural - it should be possible to model a workflow as a series of tests.

If there's no other way, this is probably how we'll do it, but we are looking for a better solution, without repeating the same setup calls.

Comment: This is hard because, in general, having tests that depend on each other is usually a very bad idea.  Few testing frameworks try to make this easy as a result.

Comment: @RossPatterson: Yes, I know the argument, and I agree - for unit tests. With integration tests, I believe (and many people agree) that dependencies can be useful. See the example I gave in my question.

Comment: BTW, I have something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808703/why-afterclass-called-after-tests-from-another-classes

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing "functionality" and "test".  Separating them will solve your problem.

For example, create a helper class/method that executes the steps to log in, then call that class/method in your Login test and all other tests that require the user to be logged in.

Your other tests do not actually need to rely on your Login "Test", just the login class/method.

If later back-end modifications introduce a bug in the login process, all of the tests which rely on the Login helper class/method will still fail as expected.

**Update:**

Turns out this already has a name, the Page Object pattern.  Here is a page with Java examples of using this pattern:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects

Comment: You do have a point (and we already use classes very much like PageObjects to encapsulate our own pages). However, we have situations where we want to test a complete workflow, with each step depending on all previous steps (see my example). To do that with "independent" tests would mean repeating the whole setup for every test. That would mean slower tests (that do the same thing over and over), and it would mean many test failures for one error in the common setup code. So this is a solution we already rejected.

Comment: And thanks for the link to PageObjects - an interesting concept. However, it does not really addres my question - our "setup" is mostly about backend setup (such as initializing the test database, and starting up helper services), not about page state.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the clarification.  A few questions: Since we are talking about integration tests your tests #1 and #2 are not necessary... #3 already covers those cases.  Also,

Comment: (oops, unexpected submission on enter) You mention this would needlessly increase testing time; I respectfully disagree. I would suggest that Test #1 is unnecessary since these are integration tests and that case will be thoroughly covered in the subsequent tests. But as Ross Patterson alluded, its important to verify the independence of your tests to prevent unexpected bleed over.  If if feels unnatural that may indicate an issue with the existing test strategy.  Hopefully not, but I have run across too many cases where steps that are supposed to be independent are not.

Comment: Happy to supply examples if you need help convincing the team (unfortunately many are from my own code). Also, since setup time seems to be an issue, you may want to ask a separate question regarding ways to minimize that for your specific scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your input. So you propose to either a) put all the steps into one test , or b) put the steps into separat tests and re-run the necessary setup for each test. We thought using tests with dependencies is the way to go, but maybe this is a better approach. We'll have to investigate this.

Answer (score 2):

Try with depends on group along with depends on method. Add all methods in same class in one group.
For example

```
@Test(groups={"cls1","other"}) 
public void cls1test1(){
}
@Test(groups={"cls1","other"}, dependsOnMethods="cls1test1", alwaysrun=true) 
public void cls1test2(){
}

In class 2
@Test(groups={"cls2","other"}, dependsOnGroups="cls1", alwaysrun=true) 
public void cls2test1(){
}
@Test(groups={"cls2","other"}, dependsOnMethods="cls2test1", dependsOnGroups="cls1", alwaysrun=true) 
public void cls2test2(){
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks. However, this forces a total ordering on the tests (i.e. different classes would always run in the same order), which is not what we need.

Comment: You can use testng.xml to run the test orderly by groups, classes, methods, packages etc. For details you can visit: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy (whilst hacky) workaround for this if you are comfortable with your first approach:

> At first we just put tests that belong together into one class, and used dependsOnMethods to make them run in the right order. This used to work in TestNG V5, but in V6 TestNG will sometimes interleave tests from different classes (while respecting the ordering imposed by dependsOnMethods). There does not seem to be a way to tell TestNG "Always run tests from one class together".

We had a similar problem: we need our tests to be run class-wise because we couldn't guarantee the test classes not interfering with each other.

This is what we did:
Put a

```
@Test( dependsOnGroups= { "dummyGroupToMakeTestNGTreatThisAsDependentClass" } )
```

Annotation on an Abstract Test Class or Interface that all your Tests inherit from.
This will put all your methods in the "first group" (group as described [in this paragraph](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors), not TestNG-groups). Inside the groups the ordering is class-wise.
Thanks to Cedric Beust, he provided a [very quick answer for this](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/106#issuecomment-2710318).

Edit:
The group `dummyGroupToMakeTestNGTreatThisAsDependentClass` actually has to exist, but you can just add a dummy test case for that purpose..

Comment: An interesting solution, thanks. We'll probably try to make the tests independent, but good to know there are other options.

Comment: Making tests independent is a better solution, the workaround has some unwanted side-effects. It especially does not work well with the Eclipse TestNG plugin.