# How to ensure that the order specified in TestNG.xml is retained?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng

On using TestNG+Selenium , I'm not able to ensure the order of execution of classes.The order specified below (in testng.xml) is not working ->ClassTwo executes first and then ClassOne is executed.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="ABC" parallel="">
  <test verbose="2" name="xyz" annotations="JDK" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="script.ClassOne"/>
      <class name="script.ClassTwo"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

How can I ensure that the order specified in  TestNG.xml is retained?

Comment: Preserve-order works for me..did a simple test.  Can you publish ur code and output..

Comment: This is still broken. Any resolution for this problem?

Answer (score 7):

You just have to set parallel value to none

```
<suite name="ABC" parallel="none">
```

it works for me !

Comment: I gave as parallel="false"  so it worked . Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

According to [TestNG documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml):

> By default, TestNG will run your tests in the order they are found in
>   the XML file. If you want the classes and methods listed in this file
>   to be run in an unpredictable order, set the preserve-order attribute
>   to false

I would suggest leaving the `preserve-order` attribute out, since it is set by default.

However, you have two other options to force specific order to the test methods/classes:

1. Invoke tests programmatically.
2. Implement [method interceptor](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors), that will order the list of the tests.

Comment: But in my case the execution flow defined in testng.xml  is not followed. I want that the execution flow should be according to testng.xml.If i leave out preserve-order the problem still persists.What can be the reason for this?

Comment: You might be using an older version of TestNG where that flag wasn't set by default. Make sure you use the latest version.

Comment: I've noticed the method order works just fine if you explicitly list them in the desired order inside a <methods /> collection within your <class> definition.  Otherwise, they're in an unpredictable order.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `@Test( dependsOnGroups= { "dummyGroupToMakeTestNGTreatThisAsDependentClass" } )` in the class?

See this thread:
[TestNG & Selenium: Separate tests into "groups", run ordered inside each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956521/testng-selenium-separate-tests-into-groups-run-ordered-inside-each-group)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

....Quite a bit after the event but I had the same problem and found myself here.

In the end it was because the individual tests had been marked with a priority in the `@Test` annotation, so in my case but your example `script.ClassTwo` had a higher priority than `script.ClassOne`

Answer (score 0):

In TestNG, the order of execution is based on alphabetical order so we could use a TestNG attribute Priority and there  we could mention which class->methods you want to execute first.This is Priority annotation attribute you could give in the @Test annotation.

example: @Test(Priority=-1)

Lesser the number value the first it will execute.